# Is there an optimal row number of lists in Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DataTable?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When ever the row number of the lists are high (what I mean is sometimes even only 170-200 rows), on scroll down/up, DataTable refreshes itself somehow and all the custom css, click functions and events are being removed. Moreover the list is sometimes freezing or scrollbar is getting stuck at the bottom.

If I dont use `DataTable.groupByColumn(5000)` the performance and css is better but I still loose click events on the table.

The reason why I use `DataTable.groupByColumn()` with an extreme number is the row style. As default the background color of rows are black and white, it is not easy to read and confusing. But anyhow even if I don't use `groupByColumn()`  I am loosing onClick functions when I scroll down on high row number lists...

Is there a way to avoid this 'refresh' or is there an optimal row number to keep in mind when we make development on DataTable ?

As an example I've created 285 row list with random strings to check if the problem is arising from our data structure but unfortunately same problem occurs in example too.

Do we have the chance to optimize it ?

**EDIT**

I have realized that `DataTable` uses '**clusterize.js**', that's why I have used event delegation instead of giving functions to each row but this time all functions are working delayed depending on the length of the list.

Anybody has any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found yourself, the `DataTable` is just a simple wrapper for the [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org) library. Any potential optimizations would therefore have to be discussed with the library's community.